# I don't understand the word "however" in this context

Tags: meaning

> In the years since transgression I have sought no absolution, only bare forgiveness. In good faith I have removed myself from all temptation, sacrificed to prove my commitment however I can imagine.

I cannot understand the last part "*sacrificed to prove my commitment however I can imagine*", so could you explain this sentence to me?

Comment: See the 3rd meaning in _however_'s entry [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/however).

Comment: @terdon: Not so. It's (AHD) conjunction usage 1 in your reference.

Comment: You may wish to check out [our sister site for English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). It’s “for people who are learning or teaching English as a foreign language”, whereas here we’re more intended “for linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace "however" with "in any way" (whichever way), that should make more sense now, right?

Comment: It becomes clearer. What a meaning of the word commitment in this sentence?

Comment: I think it can only have one interpretation in this context: "being 'committed' to a particular cause, action, or attitude" -- in the sense of pledging or devoting oneself to it.

Comment: See meaning 1 [here](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/commitment?q=commitment). Please use a dictionary *before* asking the meaning of words, and if it is still unclear, please indicate what you found and explain how/why you are still confused.

Comment: @TrevorD : What the... Oxford doesn't include the "imprisoned"/"confined" meaning of committed?

Comment: (Too late to edit above) Okay, so the action is called commital, not commitment, my bad here, but still, i couldn't find the word for the state of being *committed* in there.

Comment: @C.B. We may be at cross-purposes. My comment was directed to OP, and was written simultaneously with your comment (which I didn't see until I had posted mine). OP asked meaning of "commitment" & I pointed to definition as "the state or quality of being dedicated to a cause, activity, etc.:" (which corresponds to your defn.). Not clear why you're mentioned 'prison' meaning? [When I want to edit a comment & it's too late, I sometimes "Copy" the original, delete the comment, and then create a new one and paste & amend.]

Comment: @TrevorD : OP actually directs his query to address 'I don't understand the word “however” in this context'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But read the first comment in this chain!

Comment: @TrevorD : You need to differentiate between OP's OP and OP's first comment, then. And OP needs to limit himself to one distinct question per thread.

Comment: @TrevorD : Yes, i know you were directing your comment to the OP, but i was weakly disagreeing with your suggestion of the use of dictionaries. In my experience, they sometimes have too many meanings, making it hard to find the one corresponding to the current context; in this case however, i found that it didn't have the only other meaning i knew of (there need to be at least two dissimilar meanings for confusion to arise). PS Thanks for the suggestion about dealing with the 5-minute window on editing comments. :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree with your last point. As regards the first point, I would have had it seems necessary at the time, but when I wrote my first comment in this thread, I expected it to appear immediately below OP's comment - but C.B. got in a few minutes earlier, hence the confusion! But too late to edit/move everything now.

Comment: @C.B. OK. Understand where you're coming from now. My comment about using dictionaries first is actually based on site policy, bearing in mind that this is a "site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts." (See [about](http://english.stackexchange.com/about) and the section [What topics can I ask about here?](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), especially the last para., & on same page, the section *Where can I find answers to simple and basic questions?*, esp. the para. below the bullet points.

Comment: @TrevorD : I thought un@'d comments were generally taken to refer to the answer nearest above (unless the comments are from the answerer).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Maybe - hadn't thought of that - still learning! I know that un@'d comments get notified to answerer automatically. I had assumed they also got notified to OP - do you know if that's correct?

Comment: No, but it's a useful device, indicating what point a commenter is actually responding to in a thread. Sometimes I'll put something like '@EdwardAshman comment 3'.